# speed up/optimize pandas code

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a data-driven bond screening and I have as input a big dataset of 1526 columns and 2412 rows. For 10 columns it takes 2 minutes processing time at the moment, which is too much. The following function takes 90% of the time:

Input of the function is df: a pandas series, where the index is a time series and the first column has floats, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwwMg.jpg

```
def future_returns(df):
    grid_columns = np.arange(len(df))
    grid = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=grid_columns)

    # fill grid with copies of df, shifted 1 element forward for each column
    for no, idx in enumerate(grid.columns):
        grid.loc[:, idx] = df.shift(-no)

    # calculate future returns from every point in the index
    future_returns = grid.divide(grid.iloc[:, 0], axis=0) - 1

    return future_returns
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226)  Also, question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask] for examples.

Answer (score 1):

## code

Your code itself is clear, with and has only a few improvements

### `df`

your parameter `df` expects actually a `Series`, and not a `DataFrame`, so I would rename this.

### composition

now you first make an empty `DataFrame` and then change the values. More clear would be to generate it directly with the correct data:

```
def future_returns_2(data):
    grid = pd.DataFrame(
        index=data.index, 
        columns=np.arange(len(data)), 
        data=[data.shift(-i).values for i in range(len(data))],
    )
    return grid.divide(data, axis=0) - 1
```

Conveniently, this is also about faster

## numpy

If you really want it a lot faster, you should stay in the `numpy` space for as long as possible, and only generate the `DataFrame` at the last possible time.

You can use `numpy.roll`

```
arr = data.values
result = np.array(
    [np.roll(arr, -i) for i in range(len(arr))],
    copy=False,
) / arr - 1
```

Since `numpy.roll` doesn't make the lower triangle of the result `NaN`, You should add this yourself:

```
mask = np.rot90(np.tri(l,), k=-1)
mask[np.where(1 - mask)] = np.nan
mask
```

> ```
> array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
>        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1., nan],
>        [ 1.,  1.,  1., nan, nan],
>        [ 1.,  1., nan, nan, nan],
>        [ 1., nan, nan, nan, nan]])
> ```

Now you can deduct this `mask` instead of `1`

```
def future_returns_numpy(data):
    arr = data.values
    l = len(arr)

    mask = np.rot90(np.tri(l), k=-1)
    mask[np.where(1 - mask)] = np.nan

    result = np.array(
        [np.roll(arr, -i) for i in range(l)], 
        copy=False,
    ) / arr - mask

    return pd.DataFrame(data = result.T, index = data.index)
```

I find this code less clear than the `pandas` algorithm, but if speed is important, I would use this.

## timings

For this dummy data

```
size=1000
np.random.seed(0)
data = pd.Series(
    np.random.random(size), 
    index= pd.date_range(start='20190101', freq='1d', periods = size),
)
```

> ```
> OP: 10.4 s ± 528 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
> future_returns_2: 722 ms ± 29.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
> future_returns_numpy: 79 ms ± 7.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
> ```